# Mapbox change language in Android Studio, Java

Tags: mapbox

I installed Mapbox SDK in Android 10.15.0
I want to change my map’s label language in korean.
[document](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/change-language/)

but it fails.

My code.

1. error message : Cannot resolve method 'localizeLabels' in 'Style'

```
package com.example.myapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.mapbox.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.maps.Style;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Map_viewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_view);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        mapView.getMapboxMap().loadStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS, style -> {
            Locale koreanLocale = new Locale("ko");
            style.localizeLabels(koreanLocale);
        });
    }
```

2. error message : Cannot resolve method 'localizeLabels' in 'Style'

```
package com.example.myapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.mapbox.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.maps.Style;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Map_viewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_view);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        Locale locale = new Locale("ko");
        mapView.getMapboxMap().getStyle(style -> {
            style.localizeLabels(locale);
        });
    }
```